# What symbols have been used for "many" (or "a large amount of") or "a few" (or "a small amount of") in the history of mathematics or other fields?

Tags: notation, anthropology

When making notes recently I felt like using a symbol for "a large amount of", and it occurred to me that surely others before me must have experienced the need for such a symbol.

What symbols have been used for "many" (or "a large amount of") or "a few" (or "a small amount of") in the history of mathematics or in other fields of theoretical endeavour, or practical work or experimentation, such as medicine, chemistry, alchemy, or physics?

Edit

The concept of "many" or "a large quantity" is surely an anthropological invariant. The apparent absence of well-known symbols for it is intriguing. I would have expected there to be symbols for it in alchemy and medicine, denoting a quantity of one substance that's easily sufficient to flood out another. And is there no symbol for a "trace amount"?

Comment: "Large" and "small" are relative and completely meaningless out of context, so they are of no use in mathematics. [Little o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation) is used to indicate that one quantity is asymptotically vanishingly smaller than the other.

Comment: Double "<", like "<<" can be used to show that the left side is far smaller than the right. But it is not really math, because "far smaller" has no math definition (actually you could create one).

Comment: Many concepts in mathematics and other fields of endeavour too are relative and meaningless out of context. In mathematics there is $\epsilon$ for an *arbitrarily* small quantity when there is continuity, but I am after a symbol for a more general concept, a concept the existence of which is pretty much an anthropological invariant.

Comment: From peterh: $x \gg 1$ means $x$ is very large, and $x \ll 1$ means $x$ is very small.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1188813/for-almost-all-symbol#:~:text=I%20use%20(and%20I%20often,%2C%20%22for%20infinitely%20many%22.&text=I've%20sometimes%20come%20across,%2C%20or%20%22almost%20all%22.

Comment: I've seen the double greater than and less than symbols used without right operand to mean "very small" or "very large".  So "x >>" meaning "very large x", presumably context making "compared to what" clear.  It's pretty confusing notation though, so I think I've only seen it used in lectures. Cant recall every seeing it in a text.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica  I respectfully disagree, because "<<" is used regularly to indicate terms in a series expansion or other calculation which are so small as to be able to be dropped from the calculation without significant error.  Not all branches of math deal strictly with equalities.